# android vibrate or beep while popup MSG is generatted

Tags: android

I want vibrate or beep while  my android generated the popup msg...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the permission `android.permission.VIBRATE` to your Manifest file.

Check out the [`Vibrator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) class and call the `vibrate(long milliseconds)` when you generate your Toast.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> that kind of?

Answer (score 1):

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibrator.vibrate(vibrationDuration);
```

Comment: iTS NOT WORK.. after this write, popup msg is not generated.

Comment: put this after you show popup. The above code doesn't create a popup, just make the phone to vibrate. Add this code after you show the popup